# Finding number n bernoulli trials (probability p) needed to satisfy k successes with probability j

Tags: probability, negative-binomial

Firstly sorry for the title. I know it's not a good title, but if I knew how to describe this problem in a more elegant way I likely wouldn't have it in the first place.

The problem is the following:

You have a Bernoulli trial with a known p probability of success. You have to figure out the *smallest* number of trials n such that you have at least a j% chance of obtaining at least k successes (ie; cumulative probability X≥k is greater than j).

j,k, and p are your known variables. You are attempting to find n as the smallest number satisfying the above condition.

Given that the binomial distribution is allergic to closed form solutions I do not expect the problem above to have one, but I'm hopeful I can find a better input estimate for my code, which then uses a stepper function (iterating through higher or lower values of n) to find the true answer. Currently I am using the (very) naive estimate of k/p as a starting value.

Despite lots and lots of googling, I haven't managed to come across this exact question before, mostly stuff relating to the quantile function, which seems to be subtly different.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution is designed for questions like this.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. I did come across that in my searching, but it didn't seem to help me as all of those distributions are based off of either n or k (k of course being dependent on n). As said I'm already capable of calculating the number i want iterating through values of n. What I want is an estimator for the value which doesn't require iterating through values of n.

Comment: I think the best strategy is to use the normal approximation to the binomial. This allows you to quickly estimate the probability that $\text{Bin}(n,p)$ is at least $k$, for various values of $n$, until this approximation is close to $j\%$.. Specifically, the probability $\text{Bin}(n,p)\ge k$ is approximately the probability $N(0,1)\ge (k-1/2-np)/\sqrt{np(1-p)}$, so you just need a way to compute the cdf of the standard normal.

Comment: @Mike: the normal approximation is really not that good unless $k$ is pretty close to the expected value $np$. For more extreme values of $k$ standard large deviations results show a different tail from the normal behavior near the mean.

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be a good "closed form" solution (depending on what you mean by "closed form"), and you'll need to do some numeric root-seeking at some level.

But you're right that iteration (stepping up and down) is not a great solution.  If the software libraries you're using include a function to calculate the inverse CDF of the [negative binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) (i.e. matlab has [nbinv](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nbininv.html), python's scipy library has [nbinom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.nbinom.html).[ppf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.ppf.html#scipy.stats.rv_discrete.ppf)),
you're done.

Otherwise, you can use [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) (or any other reasonable root-finding or sorted-searching method) on the CDF (which is fairly easy to evaluate) to find the answer you need.

I think any further details are more a software or programming question.

Do note that there are multiple variations and conventions for the negative binomial distribution.  Any given function may be evaluating something different than what you expect.

### More details

The negative binomial distribution answers "how many (total $n$/non-counting $k$) samples do I have to get before I hit $r$ (your $k$, unfortunately) samples that count.  For your purposes, Wikipedia's second (or third, if you want to swap $p$ and $(1-p)$) "[alternative formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Alternative_formulations)" is appropriate.

The minimum number is the first value on the CDF that is greater than or equal to your $j$%.  The CDF is the [regularized incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) $I_p(r, k+1) = I_p(r, n + 1 - r)$ evaluated at each $n \geq r$.  This is a polynomial in $p$ for integer $r$ and $n$, but this is little help as you're working with $p$ (and $r$) fixed, and $n$ varying.  I'm unaware of any good formula to get from the values of this function to $n$, though as previously noted there are certainly canned routines in some software packages.

Comment: The programming language is python. I suspect scipy would have something I need but I wasn't specifically able to find it tbh. However, I wanted to phrase this as a maths question because I like to understand what I am implementing more than I want to deploy canned solutions. This is a personal project, not homework or work afterall.


Can you elaborate more practically on a better root finding method than iteration? Let's say I have a function which gives me the percentage of obtaining k successes. What I was doing previously was iterating the input n - what would be better?

Comment: @Arelus: bisection is just repeatedly going "y is too small, x is too big, what happens if I look at (x+y)/2 -- okay, now I know that (x+y)/2 is too small, so I'll replace y with that, and try again.  This gets closer to the right answer much more quickly than just shifting by 1.

Comment: That makes sense. For whatever reason I was barking up the wrong tree looking at binom.ppf instead of nbinom. Oh well, there's a reason I failed maths.


I understand the bisection method now although, how would you round it ((x+y) /2, since that doesnt have to be an integer yet n must be an integer)? does it particularly matter?

Comment: For the searching portion, how to round only makes a marginal difference.   However for termination ( declaring "I've found it" )  it's critical.  You need intervals of length 1 to actually terminate.  Rounding down (the default with `//` in recent python) and checking if the new element is the lower-bound will do so -- and then the upper bound is what you should return.

Comment: I have a slight problem with nbinom.ppf - either I am using it wrong, or it is giving me wrong answers. For me, nbinom.ppf(0.99,10,0.3) evaluates to 48 - yet putting those numbers into a calculator like https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~mbognar/applets/bin.html
gives me p X≥x of 0.943. The function I was using prior (correctly) returns 58

Comment: 58 = 10 + 48; it's a different convention between total and "failures".

Answer (score 1):

Using the normal approximation to the binomial, the probability that $X\ge k$ when $X\sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$ is approximately
$$
P(X\ge k)\approx 1-\Phi\left(\frac{k-\frac12-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\right)
$$
Here, $\Phi$ is the cdf of the standard normal variable.

You want to choose $n$ so that $P(X\ge k)\ge j/100$.
This is approximately true when
$$
np+\Phi^{-1}(1-j/100)\cdot \sqrt{np(1-p)}-(k-\tfrac12)=0
$$
This is a quadratic equation in the variable $\sqrt n$. Let $z=\Phi^{-1}(1-j/100)$. We get
$$
n\approx \left(\frac{-z\sqrt{p(1-p)}+\sqrt{z^2p(1-p)+4p(k-\tfrac12)^2}}{2p}\right)^2
$$
I have tested this, and I found that this approximation is very close to the true value of $n$, as long as $p$ is not too close to $0$ or $1$. In particular, this works even in the extreme case where $j\%$ is close to $0\%$ or $100\%$, contrary to Quiaochu Yuan's doubtful comments. :^)

For example, take $p=0.1, j=0.00001$, and $k=34000$. Plugging this into the above, and rounding down, you get $n\approx 331020$. This turns out to be a bit too large, and the actual smallest value of $n$ such that $P(\text{Bin}(n,p)\ge k)\ge j/100$ is $n=330987$. This is a relative error of less than $0.01\%$.

---

Below is my Python program for finding $n$ exactly. I do not use the approximate of all; it suffices to use bisection search on the binomial cdf.

```
from scipy.stats import binom

def smallest_n(p, k, j):
    """
    Returns the smallest n such that
    P(X >= k) >= j / 100, where
    X is Binomial(n, p).
    """
    def prob_X_ge_k(n):
        return 1 - binom.cdf(k - 1, n, p)
    return function_bisect(prob_X_ge_k, j/100)

def function_bisect(f, target):
    """
    f is an increasing function from the nonnegative integers to floats.
    target is a float.
    Returns the smallest x such that f(x) >= target.
    WARNING: This loops forever if there is no x for which f(x) >= target.
    """

    lower_lim = 0
    if f(lower_lim) >= target:
        return lower_lim
    
    upper_lim = 2 
    while f(upper_lim) < target:
        upper_lim *= 2

    while upper_lim - lower_lim >= 2:
        mid = (lower_lim + upper_lim) // 2
        if f(mid) >= target:
            upper_lim = mid
        elif f(mid) < target:
            lower_lim = mid
    return upper_lim

p = 0.1
j = 0.00001
k = 34000

print(smallest_n(p, k, j))
```

Comment: Huh, well, color me surprised.

Comment: I would not consider 0.1 to be that close to 0.  logodds are the reasonable distance measure on probabilities.  But yes, Qiaochu was a bit pessimistic in not accounting for two bad approximations undoing each others badness.